# convert epoc time into minutes-Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to show as an output:

```
User was online for 12 minutes
```

I'm calculating the timespent by the user on the page by setting a timeinterval.

```
     componentDidMount() {

          this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setState({ time: Date.now() }), 60000);
      }
render () {
<div> User online for {this.state.time} minutes</div>

}
```

But this gives me:

O/P:

```
User online for 1532887387453 minutes
```

Hence this conversion for converting epoch into human readable minutes.

Is this possible?

Comment: Share your requirements more clearly, what's your expected output. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using setInterval to update the time spent, why can't you simply increment the counter after each minute,

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    timeSpent: 0, // if you want to show 1 as the minimum, set as 1 here
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setState({ timeSpent: ++this.state.timeSpent }), 60000);
}
render () {
  <div> User online for {this.state.timeSpent} minutes</div>
}
```

P.S: But keeping this time calculation logic inside a component is really bad approach.

Comment: thanks @Kamalakannan J, where should I put the logic into if not component as best practise?

Comment: In this way, if you'll miss some interval your calculation will be wrong.

Comment: Do you want to capture how much time user spent without "redirection"(or "hard navigation") OR different case ?

Answer (score 2):

this time is in milliseconds. So, to get minutes, you should divide it by 1000 (to get seconds), and then by 60 (to get mniutes), or simply divide it by 60000. So, use code as the following:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { time: 0 };
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setState({ time: (Date.now() / 60000) - this.state.time }), 60000);
}

render() {
  return (<div>User online for {this.state.time} minutes</div>);
}
```

Comment: how to calculate minutes from this o/p: 25548140.800333332?

Comment: You just should subtract those minutes from the result; I updated my answer.